Trouble with summarizing data in R dataframe based on frequency of combination
I have a dataframe ("merged_coordinates") with columns: "ID", "station_lat", and "station_lng".
My aim is to create a summary table where each ID appears once, displaying the most frequent combination of station_lat and station_lng along with their count.
If for an ID there are available only combinations with the same frequency, I want to select the first available combination.
I've tried the following code with slice_max function:
summary <- merged_coordinates %>%
  group_by(ID, station_lat, station_lng) %>%
  summarise(total_count = sum(count)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(total_count == max(total_count)) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = total_count, n = 1)

However, I'm not getting the desired result. For example, ID 1012 is repeated multiple times:
ID       station_lat station_lng total_count
<chr>    <dbl>       <dbl>       <int>
021320   41.89000    -87.68000   528
1011     41.92374    -87.78584   17
1012     41.80486    -87.60910   1
1012     41.80486    -87.60913   1
1012     41.80487    -87.60911   1
1012     41.80487    -87.60911   1


I tried using filter(row_number() == 1), but it doesn't seem right to me. slice_max function seemed more appropriate. What am I doing wrong?
Here's some toy data:
structure(list(ID = c("021320", "021320", "021320", "021320", 
"1011", "1011", "1011", "1011", "1012", "1012", "1012", "1012", 
"1013", "1013", "1013", "1013", "1015", "1015", "1015", "1015", 
"1016", "1016", "1016", "1016", "1017", "1017", "1017", "1017", 
"1018", "1018", "1018", "1018", "1019", "1019", "1019", "1019", 
"1020", "1020", "1020", "1020", "1023", "1023", "1023", "1023", 
"1027", "1027", "1027", "1027", "1028", "1028", "1028", "1028", 
"1029", "1029", "1029", "1029", "1030", "1030", "1031", "1031", 
"1031", "1031", "1032", "1032", "1032", "1032", "1033", "1033", 
"1033", "1033", "1034", "1034", "1036", "1036", "1036", "1036", 
"1037", "1037", "1037", "1037", "1038", "1038", "1038", "1038", 
"1039", "1039", "1039", "1039", "1040", "1040", "1040", "1040", 
"1042", "1042", "1042", "1042", "1043", "1043", "1043", "1043"
), station_lat = c(41.89, 41.889609814, 41.889638, 41.889652014, 
41.92, 41.923543453, 41.9237903333333, 41.923790336, 41.80486083, 
41.804864287, 41.804867148, 41.8048708333333, 41.8853048333333, 
41.885427237, 41.885514259, 41.8855685, 41.9900668333333, 41.9901176666667, 
41.9901861666667, 41.9902456666667, 41.9901981666667, 41.990226, 
41.9902383333333, 41.9902425, 41.975550771, 41.9755558333333, 
41.975573659, 41.9755741666667, 41.93, 41.9278755, 41.9278978333333, 
41.9279095, 41.93, 41.931578875, 41.9316343333333, 41.93165, 
41.880537152, 41.880629182, 41.880814791, 41.880919456, 41.73, 
41.72693646, 41.7269485, 41.726949215, 41.78, 41.77908957, 41.77916491, 
41.7791941666667, 41.778780937, 41.7788145, 41.778899789, 41.778924227, 
41.779306531, 41.78, 41.779343, 41.78, 41.78, 41.777732, 41.78, 
41.778617978, 41.77867043, 41.778681755, 41.7786823333333, 41.778713, 
41.7786281666667, 41.778761, 41.77, 41.773444414, 41.773555517, 
41.773599505, 41.778493, 41.78, 41.784883022, 41.784888625, 41.7848893333333, 
41.78489244, 41.78, 41.779486179, 41.7795041666667, 41.7795113333333, 
41.7799501666667, 41.779985, 41.78, 41.780029893, 41.78, 41.781784, 
41.7817951666667, 41.7818381666667, 41.82, 41.822534, 41.822538, 
41.822558045, 41.8, 41.801276684, 41.8012863333333, 41.8012901666667, 
41.81, 41.808716893, 41.808746, 41.81), station_lng = c(-87.68, 
-87.680438161, -87.6803506666667, -87.680357814, -87.79, -87.785579562, 
-87.7857561666667, -87.785757184, -87.609097004, -87.609130621, 
-87.609107971, -87.609114, -87.7261246666667, -87.725667596, 
-87.725642562, -87.725978, -87.7176285, -87.7172083333333, -87.7172116666667, 
-87.7171563333333, -87.7156363333333, -87.7156491666667, -87.7156108333333, 
-87.7155816666667, -87.717754245, -87.7177183333333, -87.717770457, 
-87.7177385, -87.74, -87.7359225, -87.7360308333333, -87.7360333333333, 
-87.74, -87.737184644, -87.7373493333333, -87.7374683333333, 
-87.72092855, -87.720946431, -87.720947623, -87.720810294, -87.65, 
-87.654961109, -87.6548763333333, -87.654958844, -87.69, -87.692977905, 
-87.692967772, -87.6928921666667, -87.699607015, -87.6995738333333, 
-87.700064659, -87.700085521, -87.686949372, -87.69, -87.686763, 
-87.69, -87.71, -87.713878, -87.72, -87.723518968, -87.72338593, 
-87.723702431, -87.7268828333333, -87.72691, -87.7270278333333, 
-87.726892, -87.72, -87.722876668, -87.722751379, -87.72279501, 
-87.7333856666667, -87.73, -87.703196526, -87.703235865, -87.7031718333333, 
-87.703182936, -87.71, -87.708001018, -87.7079003333333, -87.707906, 
-87.7031965, -87.7032071666667, -87.7, -87.703271151, -87.7, 
-87.7032153333333, -87.7032371666667, -87.7032801666667, -87.69, 
-87.6906996666667, -87.6905955, -87.690538764, -87.66, -87.662082553, 
-87.6621116666667, -87.6622278333333, -87.66, -87.660102963, 
-87.66026, -87.66), count = c(276L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



slice_max, by default, keeps all tied values if there are ties. Set with_ties = FALSE in your slice_max() to get only one. See the ?slice_max help page for details. (You can probably also get rid of the filter() line entirely.)

But also, the slice functions are nicely convenient for stuff like this, but filter() is the general purpose tool here. Don't feel bad about using filter(row_number() == 1). (But of course it's good to ask a question like this and better understand the slice variants.)
